# Fingering for long arpeggio

Tags: piano, fingering, arpeggios

I seek fingering advice for the arpeggio in the image shown. It’s in A Major.[image: arpeggio].

Comment: I assume both clefs are treble? What fingerings have you tried, and what problems have you encountered?

Answer (score 3):

Both trebles, I presume. From the l.h. going up, 5, 2, 1. r.h. 1, 2, 3, 5.

Since it's arpeggiated, sustain pedal will help, even if not indicated. Move the l.h. along as you play each note.

It would sound better using the sostenuto pedal, if available, as the held chord could make the second half sound a bit muddy.

Comment: Or (for left hand) 5, 3, 1. It might be more of a better choice going with 5, 2, 1, but it feels more comfortable for my hand to do so, so it might with others.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I have no problem with r.h, but l.h, I have to use finger 2 ( middle note E) as a pivot so I could reach the C#, it’s a long span for me. To roll on those 3 notes as arpeggiated, it’s not easy. I  suppose I have to practice more. BTW, I’m new here, didn’t expect I could get the answer right away, this is a very helpful platform for the learners. Great!

Answer (score 0):

The whole notes cannot be held without using the sustain pedal. This music does not make a whole lot of sense because the pedal would need to be changed in order to keep the music from sounding muddy and quite dissonant in beats 3 and 4. However, changing the pedal would cancel out the whole note, reducing them to two beats. It is difficult to know what the composer intended here.